# Black screen while accessing xrdp in RHEL 7.9

Tags: rhel7, xrdp

We have installed xrdp and tigerVNC server in RHEL 7.9 server. As Internet was not available we have mounted the iso file and installed the dependencies. Xrdp package was not a part of default iso repository hence we added that package explicitly.

Currently when we launch Remote Desktop connection for rhel 7.9 GUI

We get the xrdp validation window where we put username and password
But once we click on OK button we get the BLACK WINDOW.

Kindly let us know what could be the root cause.
How we can overcome this problem

Tried restarting the tiger VNC and xrdp service